# Different performance of Javascript on different fiddles and chrome itself

Tags: javascript, performance, performance-testing, jsfiddle

As a newcomer to Javascript coming from a background in C#, I conducted a basic performance test to compare the performance of JS with that of C#. To my surprise, the same code produced different performance results across different fiddles. Can you explain why this may be the case?

```
var start = performance.now();

var iterations = 100000000;

for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
  var j = i * i;
}

var end = performance.now();

var time = end - start;
alert('Execution time: ' + time);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sfcu2vo6/4/

https://es6console.com/

I noticed that most websites take around 3 seconds to execute the code, but on Jsfiddle it only takes around 80ms. What is the reason for this difference in performance?

**Update**

After writing the same code in an HTML file and executing it in Chrome, I still see the same discrepancy. Can you explain why this may be happening?

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <script>

        var start = performance.now();    
        var iterations = 100000000;       
        for (var i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
        {
          var j = i * i;
        }

        var end = performance.now();    
        var time = end - start;
        alert('Execution time: ' + time);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am surprised to see that it takes more than 3 seconds to execute the code on most websites, but Jsfiddle is able to run it faster. Can you explain why Jsfiddle may have faster performance in this scenario?

**Update 2**

I found it interesting that when I saved the code as an .htm file on my desktop and ran it, it took around 80ms like Jsfiddle. However, when I ran the same code from another .htm file, it took around 3 seconds like the other websites. I am confused by this discrepancy. Can someone please try this and confirm if they experience the same results?

**Update 3**

I have discovered that the reason the code was running faster on Jsfiddle is because it was wrapped in `window.onload = function() {}`. As a beginner, I made a mistake by not including this code in my initial tests. I am relieved to have found the reason for the difference in performance.

Comment: Notice that such a microbenchmark is doomed anyway. A good optimising compiler [will drop the no-op loop entirely](https://mrale.ph/blog/2012/12/15/microbenchmarks-fairy-tale.html).

Comment: @Bergi Okay! That is sad news! :( You mean the actually performance is the one the other fiddles show right? The JsFiddle ignores the `var j = i * i` part and that is why it is faster?

Comment: @Bergi I updated my answer again! Very confused.

Comment: No, I don't know why it works differently. Assuming the environment is the same (as should be for your two html files), the optimiser should affect both by the same amount.

Comment: @Bergi I had done a very noobish mistake! The second one was inside `window.onload = function() {` That is the reason it runs faster! I think JsFiddle is also doing something like this and the other consoles are not doing it!

Comment: Yeah, maybe the optimiser doesn't run on code that executes immediately at startup. However this does not explain "*I saved as my .htm file with this code inside under different name [and now it runs differently*".

Comment: @Bergi It seems I had changed it a bit by adding this window.onload and had forgotten it! Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If you take a trace in the [Chrome performance tab](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference) while executing this code, you'll see that most of the time spent is in es6console.com's code bundles, rather than your function.

I didn't dig into exactly what they are doing, but it's possibly related to the fact that es6console transpiles the code using Babel. In general it's best not to rely on fiddles for performance testing since there are several ways they can add additional overhead on top of your code.

Comment: Thanks Joru, this meas JsFiddle is closer to truth?

Comment: I believe so, but to verify the true runtime you can always create an empty html page that only has your code and nothing else.

Comment: Actually the performance is better when the code is run inside the `window.onload = function() {`. Some of these fiddles do that and some do not. That was the reason for bad performance.

Comment: That can bypass some of the overhead they introduce in some cases, but it's not the case that code will always run faster in an onload function.